# Flutter image_picker don't save origin name / how to save the original file name?

Tags: flutter, image

I use pickedFile to save an video from my device. And I have some problems. After selecting an video from the gallery, it changes its name to something else (image_picker6849334646212907222). How to get the original name from the video?

[image]

```
Future<File> captureAndSaveVideo() async {
File _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();
final pickedFile = await picker.getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

setState(() {
  _image = File(pickedFile.path);
});
var videoName = pickedFile.path.split('/').last;
if (_image == null) return null;
//final fileName = path.basename(_image.path);

try {
  final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  print('File path is :${videoName}');
  if (directory != null)
    return _image.copy('${directory.path}/${videoName}');
  ;
} catch (e) {
  return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path)

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;


var videoName = path.basename( pickedFile.path);
```